# How do I hide/show items in a CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an instance of `System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox` which displays a list of tick boxes and I have some other `System.Windows.Forms` objects in my application. I would like to, depending on what the user selects using the other `System.Windows.Forms` items, **show or hide different items** in the `System.Windows.Form.CheckedListBox`. How could I achieve this?

**Note: this is for a windows desktop application, not a webpage.**

Comment: You are getting all these bad answers because your question is so sloppy.  It is a CheckedListBox.

Comment: @Hans: I understood what he was trying to ask. My answer is not bad, it's just to help him in the right direction. You can't expect me to post a whole solution.

Comment: @Hans Why not just edit the question? :)

Comment: @bzlm - too late, isn't it?  And this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/  Downvote sloppy questions and they'll stop coming.

Comment: Sorry for the sloppy question I guess...it seems pretty straight forward to me...

Should I have said:
I have an instance of System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox which displays a list of tick boxes and I have some other System.Windows.Forms objects in my application. I would like to, depending on what the user selects using the other System.Windows.Forms items, show or hide different items in the System.Windows.Form.CheckedListBox. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy way to hide an item in a `CheckedListBox`, you have to remove it, like Brendan Vogt showed you.

An alternative is to take advantage of data binding. It is not *supposed* to work for `CheckedListBox`, the documentation of the `DataSource` property says:

> This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.
>   Gets or sets the data source for the control. This property is not relevant for this class.

However, I used it in the past, and it works fine. So if you assign a `DataView` as the `DataSource` for the list, you can filter its items using the `RowFilter` property

```
DataView view = new DataView(productsDataTable);
checkedListBox.DataSource = view;
checkedListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
...

// Hide discontinued products
view.RowFilter = "Discontinued = False";
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a checked list box control to a window form.  This is a very basic example.  I also added a button.  When the button is clicked it removed the first item.  Here is the code that is in my button's event handler to remove the first item:

```
if (checkedListBox1.Items.Count > 0)
{
   checkedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

You can modify this code to suit your needs.

Comment: Ok I'll try this soon.I'm not 100% that familiar with how things work with rendered form elements...but if this is a desktop application, does css stuff like 'display: none' work?

Comment: @Richard. Yes it would. Put the code into a web page to give it a test in your web browser.

Comment: That's the prob though, it's not a webpage, it's a desktop application. I know that css code works for webpage elements, but does it work for desktop applications?

Comment: CSS won't work in a windows application. Give me a moment then I will get some code posted to you :)