# Hide or Show certain ListBox items in C# depending on button clicked

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem

I have one Form in my WindowsForm in C# that has two tabs. Each tab has their own separate listbox that should only display the created listbox items from the corresponding tabs (for example, a class of names). I also have separate refresh buttons that simply clear the ListBox items and add all names that have been added to the name class. I'm trying to edit the refresh buttons so that the individual listboxes only show the names that have been created under the separate tabs. Is there any code to help with this or implementation of some sort of loop?

```
  NamesList.Items.Clear();  
      //for (int i = 0; i < Globals.namecount; i++)  
      //  
      //    NamesList.Items.Add(Globals.allnames[i].Name);  
      //}
```

EDIT: This is the code for when you click the refresh button. I need to adjust this loop so that when I add to the NameList on the first tab, it doesn't automatically add all the Names that have also been created on the second tab of my Form page.

Comment: Can you please provide the source code, what have you implemented so far? And please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @OguzOzgul I have added the code that I commented out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879086/how-do-i-hide-show-items-in-a-checkedlistbox